# Unable to use Test Suite property in Soap Ui while running Soap Ui script from eclipse

Tags: soapui

We use Soap Ui for API testing. At many places we use Test Suite property to store values which needs to be passed between two tests. This works fine from the tool. However we also call the rest APIs from selenium scripts which we have developed using eclipse. Here it seems the value of Test Suite property are not being retained and scripts are failing due this reason.

Comment: Sample script to reproduce the issue please?

Comment: Eclipse code:

WsdlProject project=new WsdlProject("E:\\IAPI\\Automation\\BookingEngineAir-soapui-project.xml");
//Grab the Test suite in the project
WsdlTestSuite testsuite=project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite");

//Grab the testcases present in test suite
//for(int i=0;i<testsuite.getTestCaseCount();i++)
//{
// WsdlTestCase testCase =testsuite.getTestCaseAt(i);
WsdlTestCase testCase =testsuite.getTestCaseByName("LCC Domestic Oneway Direct Flight");


WsdlTestCaseRunner runner=testCase.run(new PropertiesMap(), false);